# How to Changetext on window resize with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change my text by the current browser width size without having to use refresh like mediaqueries.

I have this code,
It doesnt work, what am i doing wrong?

```
 function checkSize() {
   //small-screen
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
       $("#hello-world").html("Hello World");
    }
    //end small-screen
   }

  checkSize();

$(window).resize(function() {
 checkSize();
 });
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What's your HTML and let us know the full code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aaray/1/ this code seems to be Ok. Check if it is located after jquery script or use `document.ready` like suggested below. If nothing helps - see if you can show some more code. And check your console in browser. Possibly there are some errors

Comment: Thnx for you replies, the code seems oké but i get this error, 
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 

$(document).ready(function(){

Im a nooby btw, already found this: but i dont get how to use it:

http://codeimpossible.com/2010/01/13/solving-document-ready-is-not-a-function-and-other-problems/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Suggestion

Enclose the code inside `$(document).ready();` this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        checkSize();
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rXERS/

Comment: Thnx for your replie, the code seems oké but i get this error, ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined $(document).ready(function(){ Im a nooby btw, already found this: but i dont get how to use it: http://codeimpossible.com/2010/01/13/solving-document-ready-is-not-a-function-and-other-problems/ thnx for your help so far, your way is much cleaner

Comment: Just check if you have included the `jquery.js` from the correct path. Make sure that is done in the head. Else use this code `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and place it inside the `<head>`. This should work.

Comment: You are Awesome, I had my jquery reference under the textchanger.js, when i switched places it worked perfectly, Much thnx.